# how can i get the radio button inside a Wpf item template column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i hv a problem i m using Wpf Grid there is one itemtemplate column(radio button) my grid first row bind always with my form load event but the radio button is not selected..i want 
bind the row with radio button selcted

how can i achive it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a boolean in the your model class and bind the `Radiobutton.IsChecked` to that property.  Then you will just have to set that property in your model to make the button be checked.